# How to make Bonjour (mDNS) work over OpenVPN?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, bonjour

I have a server running Debian 8. Recently I installed OpenVPN on it using [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-debian-8) tutorial. Everything is working nicely. I tested on my macbook using the Tunnelblick client. Used Google to check my IP, connected to the VPN checked again and it changed to the same IP as my servers LAN. So I know that's all good.

My problem is that the File Shares on all the computers (all OSX's AFP protocol) on that LAN do not show up on my Finders sidebar while I'm connected through the VPN. Am able to connect to them manually using Finder's "Connect to Server" tool by connecting to `afp://192.168.0.100` and that works nicely. So I'm assuming it's a problem with Bonjour.

From my research I've found out that Bonjour (mDNS) does not broadcast to different subnets. So I ran `ifconfig` on my macbook while connected through the VPN. it was 192.168.43.206. All of the computers on the network I'm connecting to are **192.168.0.10** to **192.168.0.200**. So I'm guessing that's the source of my problem?

I think my solution might be to switch my OpenVPN config to "bridge" mode? I read some forums and articles which pointed to this as the solution, But I'm not even sure if I've diagnosed my problem correctly. And I haven't really grasped with Bridge mode setting.

Hoping someone can give me some clarity.

Comment: I had a similar issue with my RDP protocol. What I ended up doing was resubnetting my network so that everything was on the same network. That fixed my issue. I used the connection type that forwarded all Ethernet frames, not just the ip protocol. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, the problem with mDNS/Bonjour is that it's implemented
using the so-called [multicasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast),
and multicast packets do not automatically crosss network boundaries
(due to both the protocol's design and the design of Linux).

You might want to use something like [`smcroute`](http://troglobit.github.io/project/smcroute/) to tunnel multicast
traffic between all the networks your OpenVPN instance connects.

See [this](https://blog.michael.kuron-germany.de/2016/03/snom-voip-phones-openvpn-and-multicast-audio/) for more info,
and [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=openvpn+smcroute) in general.

Another possibility is to switch OpenVPN from `tun` mode to `tap`.
Unfortunately, this has its repercussions which must be considered
thoroughly before implementing.

Comment: Thanks, It looks like smcroute can do what I want. as i've read up on vpn bridging and don't think I want that. but I don't think I have enough knowledge on networking to make it work. I think I want to connect my eth0 interface to the tun0. But the IP groups and whatnot have me lost.

Comment: Alright, looks like it's even worse (or better): the last message in [this thread](https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=66912) says that 1) it's apparently still impossible to route mdns's packets using a multicast router, but 2) `avahi`, the stock Linux mdns server, can work as a "repeater" for mdns packets.

Comment: Looks like it's the "reflector" mode — see [this](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/avahi-daemon/avahi-daemon.conf.5.en.html#SECTION_%5BREFLECTOR%5D).

Comment: Ah cool! That might work well, I'm already running avahi on the same server that's hosting the VPN. I'm gonna read up on that and see if it works!

Comment: @tylermackenzie Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Sucks that TAP is no longer an option for MacOS since apple deprecated it ugh. So now you're forced to use avahi (if using pfsense or others) to replicate mDNS records across zones. Struggling getting it to work myself.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/500055)